# Symfony 5.3 password hashing changed back from "$argon2id" to "$2y$13"

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5, symfony-security

I am updating a Symfony app from 5.2 to 5.3

I see that after login, the password in DB is changed from `$argon2id$v=19$m=65536,t=4,p=...` to `$2y$13$f...`

In 4.4 I had implemented migrations as described [here](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-4-password-migrations), now I renamed to `password_hashers` as described [here](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-3-passwordhasher-component) (but the same thing happens with `encoders`).

What I don't understand is if this change is intended or not. I know this algorithm with `$2y$13` (I don't know its name, sorry I'm not an encryption expert) was used in the past, I have users that haven't logged in since 2020 that have still their password hashes starging with `$2$13y`

Have they reverted the default algorithm to that one? I don't find any info about that, or am I doing something wrong? In `security.yaml` I have:

```
password_hashers:
    App\Entity\User:
        algorithm: auto
```

Comment: Has something changed in your environment? For example have you switched from PHP 8 to PHP 7.4? On older versions (< PHP 8) you need to (install and) enable the PHP Module `Sodium` in the `php.ini`. In PHP 8 Sodium comes pre-installed and pre-enabled. Not sure if this enabling started in PHP 7.4 or 8.0, but that could be something to check. Symfony chooses the strongest available for your system when you have `auto` as the `algorithm` value.

Comment: I didn't change anything else, and happened in both local and prod... `dd($newHashedPassword, function_exists('sodium_hex2bin'))` returns `$2y$13$RGo40o..., true`

Comment: Happens in both local (windows, php8.0) and prod (ubuntu, php7.4), weird...

Answer (score 1):

This surprised me too. Haven't seen it documented on the [changelog](https://github.com/symfony/security-bundle/blob/5.3/CHANGELOG.md).

It's mentioned on the documentation, but on a **very** subtle way (as a comment in one of the configuration examples, [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#c-hashing-passwords)).

Between 5.2 and 5.3 the default algorithm when selecting `auto` as an option **changed from Sodium to Bcrypt**. The actual change was performed on [this commit](https://github.com/symfony/password-hasher/commit/de7a871e9ab616f105cbac4767fa1bdf69fcc806#diff-f554f2e8aedb0dc6c25450b0ff91ef2c835033c31ccd8fc9024e24ae7a026000R107).

The take away is: **if you want to use Sodium, you'll have to enable it explicitly in your configuration** (use  `sodium` instead of  `auto`).

Your passwords hashed with different algorithms will be recognized anyway, and since you have already implemented the `PasswordUpgraderInterface`, the hashes will be migrated back to Sodium.